# Upload to absolute path in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to get upload_to of FileField to be an absolute path rather than relative to MEDIA_ROOT. If I make the path absolute I get a 400 error on post of file. If no leading / it stores under MEDIA_ROOT. The uploaded document needs to be held securely and not under MEDIA_ROOT but I also have images that need to go into MEDIA_ROOT so can't change it to be out public area.

This is my code...

```
class Document(models.Model):
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    path = os.path.join( settings.DOCUMENT_DIR,  str(instance.client.id), 'documents',  str(instance.id), filename)
    return path

uploaded = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=get_upload_path, max_length=255)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: may be try django  get_absolute_url()  method

Comment: I can't see how that would help. I think I just found some doc that supports why I am having a problem. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12589 That's all very well but I need to do it and can't see why Django would force me to upload documents to an insecure location when I am quite clear in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a different [`FileSystemStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class) instance for each storage location.

Alternatively, you could write a [custom storage system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-file-storage/) to handle the files.